# Deleting a pointer from a vector... Error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector, stdvector

I'm getting the error after I delete a pointer from the vector and try to delete a second one. I'm still new to pointers

I created a base class of shapes and have multiple shapes derived classes not shown here and I have to store them in a vector of pointers.

I ask the user to add shapes of their choice measures and calculate the volumes
then I also ask what shapes they want to remove.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Luggage {
    private:
        static double totalVolume;
    
    protected:
        string type;
        static int count;
        static int serialGen;
        int serialNum;
    
    public:
        Luggage() {
            type = "Luggage";
            count++;
            serialNum = serialGen++;
            cout<<"Generating Luggage"<<getSN()<<endl;
        }
        
        // 'static' can only be specified in the class header file not source
        void static updateVolume(double inVolume) {
            totalVolume += inVolume;
        }
        
        virtual 
        ~Luggage() {
            cout<<"Luggage Destructor"<<getSN()<<endl;
            count--;
        }
        
        static int getCount() {
            return count;
        }
        
        string getType() {
            return type;
        }
        
        string getSN() {
            return "(SN: " + to_string(serialNum) + ")";
        }
        
        virtual double getVolume()=0;
        
        static double getLuggageVolume() {
            return totalVolume;
        };
        
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Luggage * lptr) {
            out<<setw(10)<<left<<lptr->getType()<<": "
                <<setw(6)<<right<<setprecision(1)
                <<fixed<<lptr->getVolume()<<"  ~  "<<lptr->getSN();
            return out;
        }
};



class Box : public Luggage {
    private:
        double length, width, height;
        static int count;
        static double totalVolume;
        
    public:
        Box(double l, double w, double h){
            count++;
            type = "Box";
            length = l;
            width = w;
            height = h;
            cout<<"Generating a Box with a Volume: "<<getVolume()<<getSN()<<endl;
            updateVolume(getVolume());
        }
        
        ~Box() {
            count--;
            updateVolume(getVolume() * -1);
            cout<<"Destroying a Box with Volume: "<<getVolume()<<getSN()<<endl;
        }
        
        double getVolume() {
            return length*width*height;
        }
        
        static int getCount() {
            return count;
        }
        static double getTotalVolume() {
            return totalVolume;
        }
};


int main() {
    // Your main program will create a container of luggage and be able to add luggage items
    // and remove them as well. This container will be a vector of luggage pointers.
    vector<Luggage*> container;

    int input;  // Main Menu User input
    bool io = true;
    while(io){
        // Main Menu
        cout << "\n----Main Menu----\n"
                "1) Add Luggage to storage container\n"
                "2) Remove Luggage from storage container\n"
                "3) Show all luggage\n"
                "4) Show total volumes\n"
                "5) Exit\n\n"
                "Enter: ";
        Luggage *lptr;

        cin >> input;
        if(input == 1){
            int shapeChoice;
            cout<<"\nWhat Shape do you want? "<<endl
                    <<"1) Box"<<endl
                    <<"2) Cube"<<endl
                    <<"3) Cylinder"<<endl
                    <<"4) Pyramid"<<endl
                    <<"5) Sphere"<<endl;
            cin>>shapeChoice;

            switch (shapeChoice){
                case 1: {   // Box
                    double length, width, height;
                    cout << "\nEnter length of Box: ";
                    cin >> length;
                    cout << "Enter width of Box: ";
                    cin >> width;
                    cout << "Enter height of Box: ";
                    cin >> height;
                    lptr = new Box(length, width, height);
                    container.push_back(lptr);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    cout << "Bad choice! Please try again later.\n";
                    break;
            }

        }else if(input == 2) {

            int count = 0;
            for(auto l:container) // container is vector<Luggage*>
                cout << ++count << ") "<< l << endl;

            cout<<"What element do you want to remove? "<<endl;
            int removeChoice;
            cin>>removeChoice;
            removeChoice-=1;

            delete (lptr);
            container.erase(container.begin()+removeChoice);

        }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and keep track of the `new` and `delete` calls. You will find that you delete something more times than you new it.

Answer (score 0):

> `delete (lptr);`

This statement is wrong.

`lptr` is pointing at the last `Box` object pushed into the vector. If nothing was pushed yet, this statement causes *undefined behavior* since `lptr` is uninitialized before the 1st push. Otherwise, you are destroying the last object pushed, and then you are left with a dangling pointer, which will then fail on the next `delete`, causing *undefined behavior* again, unlese you push a new object that updates `lptr` beforehand.

That statement should be this instead:

`delete container[removeChoice];`

or safer:

`delete container.at(removeChoice);`

since you are not validating `removeChoice` beforehand.

But either way, you really shouldn't `new`/`delete` objects manually in modern C++. Use smart pointers instead, in this case `std::unique_ptr<Luggage>`, and let it deal with destroying objects for you.